# Order of execution of jquery document ready

Tags: jquery

Suppose, I have a js file which looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // first task} );
$(document).ready(function() { // second task } );
$(document).ready(function() { // third task } );
```

Upon loading the file the tasks get executed in order. I am not able to understand why ?
I'm guessing that the callback methods are fired when an "on ready" event occurs. How is the execution order being retained ? Are the consecutive call backs being queued up in some place ?

Note: I know that this is a very naive way of coding. I have written the snippet only to get my point across and do not write such code in my projects.

Comment: I won't submit an answer because I'm not sure, but doesn't .ready add an event listener, and the event listeners are triggered in order or their being added?

Comment: What would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your handlers are being [pushed into an array](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L243) ([`readyList`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L45)) for executing [*in order* later](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L374), when the `document` [is ready](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L361).

[They're queued like this](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L243):

```
readyList.push( fn );
```

[And executed when ready like this](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L373):

```
var fn, i = 0;
while ( (fn = readyList[ i++ ]) ) {
  fn.call( document, jQuery );
}
```

If the document is *already* ready, then they'll execute immediately, which is still in order.

Comment: @Nick: in 1.4.3 you can control the order of execution, no?

Comment: @jAndy - You can't, though you can *delay* the execution of all `ready` handlers, basically saying "hey wait I'm creating more elements!".

Comment: @Nick: Ah interesting. Even if I can't imagine a usecase  ad hoc.

Comment: @jAndy - You can see the commit here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/747ba7defd82bffa6c7ccb69e53b834cbfddb62c It was originally added to allow async script loading and such to finish, ticket's here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6781

Comment: @Nick: thanks. I read the comments from burke & resig, but still I wouldn't know when & why to use. Well, the `.ready()` event does not fire if you load a script by dynamic script tag insertion? I'm doing that in almost all of my scripts without any problems. Or did I missunderstand the whole issue.

Comment: @jAndy - The issue is it may have *already* fired before your script loaded, so  you'd be allowed to delay that `ready` execution...I agree I'll probably never use it, *could* come in handy though.

Comment: My Use Case.
I implemented a `mediator pattern`, like `Symfony EventDispatcher`,
in cases where you have one `ready()` firing an event, and another `ready()` subscribing a Listener for that message, you want the later subscribing the listener before the former firing the event. 
Any trick to force an order?

Comment: @juanmf don't attach the listener on-ready if it doesn't need to wait for it, just attach it immediately - if that's not an option then there's no trick, just have to bind it before.

Answer (score 5):

The functions which you specify are in order added to a list. When the DOM is ready, jQuery iterates through that list and invokes the functions in that order.

Your list becomes something like..

```
handlers = [ function(){ alert('first') }, function() { alert('second')} ];
```

Then a loop iterates through...

```
for ( var i = 0, l = handlers.length; i<l; ++i ) {
    handlers.apply( document, arguments )
}
```

And the functions are called in the context of the document.

Comment: They're not handled quite like this, they're executed in a way that `jQuery(funcition($) { });` works :)

Comment: it was a pseudo example, the `handlers` basically is `readyList`.

Comment: I was referring to how they're being called :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the better, but inside $(window).load you could have more control. after $(document).ready

```
$(window).load( fn );
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I wanted to make reused snippet of code with a document ready, and to be used in many places. I didn't want the parent/calling pages that include it to have to specifically call the function in this snippet, but I wanted it to be run last after the document ready of the parent/calling code. The parent document ready would always be added after my document ready in the snippet, so they would be called in the wrong order.

To solve this I did this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { // When document ready, call document ready to place this function
    $(document).ready(function() { // at the end of the document ready queue, so it gets run last.
        my-snippet-js;
    });
});
</script>
```

So, at document ready, it adds my function to the end of the document ready queue so it fires last.