# calling jquery method cannot find the plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have this code in my html file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.anotherdomain.com/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.keyCode({code: "google"});
</script>
```

In `http://www.anotherdomain.com/javascript.js` there is this function defined:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.keyCode = function(params){
        params = $.extend( {code: "grid"}, params); 
        var key_code = params.code;
        $("html").live("keypress", function(e){
            if (cookieIsSet() == false){
              check_key_pressed(key_code, e);
            } 
        });
    };
});
```

The app cannot find the `$.keyCode` method.

Answer (score 2):

You definition of `jQuery.keyCode` is only available after document is ready. And `$.keyCode({code: "google"});` is executed before it, thus leading to the undefined problem.

<strike>To fix it, you should remove the `$(document).ready` wrapper.</strike>

Comment: ok, but the `.live` event needs to be in `document.ready` while still having access to the `key_code` param from the plugin. How would I do that?

Comment: While you are right with the reason, you are wrong with the remedy. Removing the document ready wrapper is the wrong thing to do. @JustinMeltzer: Just put your `$.keyCode({code: "google"});` in its own document ready wrapper. *(Also see [Order of execution of jquery document ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934570/order-of-execution-of-jquery-document-ready) here on SO.)*

Comment: @JustinMeltzer Simply wrap the `document.ready` around the `live` parts. BTW, you really shouldn't be using `live` after `jQuery 1.7`, use `on` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.anotherdomain.com/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.keyCode({code: "google"});
    });
</script>
```

Or you could even use this, which fires even later:

```
$(window).load(function() {...});
```