# Multiple calls to $(document).ready on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, document-ready

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function() sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections)

**Is it OK to have multiple calls to *$(document).ready* on the same page? If so how is the order that the code is run in resolved and does this have any implications**

I am using jQuery in my rails app. I have several levels of javascript used through the application, all of which use jQuery.

For example I have some default code that fades out Flash Notices in my application.js
I have a projects.js file that is included in all Project model views, and I have a project/edit.js that is included only in the view rendered by the edit action.

In all three js files I am using:

```
$(document).ready
{
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: yes.....its ok to have multiple calls to  $(document).ready . and the order of code run is depends on which js is loading first.

Comment: @ManseUK That's a good link, but I think this question is slightly different.

Comment: @1ndivisible thats why it has the word "Possible" on the front of the comment

Comment: You can also check the accepted answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934570/order-of-execution-of-jquery-document-ready

Comment: @ManseUK Yes. I understand that. I was simply outlining why I don't think it's a duplicate. That's why I used the words "I think" in my comment.

Comment: @1ndivisible we could go on forever :-) ... the answers below give you what you need and its not been closed so all is good ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fine.

The execution order will be in the same order they were used.

**First in First Out**

jQuery has an internal queue called `readyList` storing all the callbacks for the ready event. When you call the `ready` function with a callback is simply add it to the queue and fire the whole queue when the DOM is ready.

Looking at the jQuery source code can tell you that easily:

**source code:**

```
// The deferred used on DOM ready
readyList,
...
...

ready: function( fn ) {
    ...
    // Add the callback
    readyList.add( fn );

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They run [the same order they were attached](http://jsfiddle.net/ADJ4u/) and it's fine to do so. However, you could do [a shorter equivalent](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) to lessen function calls since `$(document).ready()` by itself is 2 function calls

```
$(function(){
    //document is ready
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Calls to $(document).ready in jQuery are executed in the order that they are defined.
More info here
[http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMultiple_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)