# Execute JS script after all other script controls registered

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, client-side

I have a bunch of .NET controls which register their client side during $(document).ready(). I also have a client side controller which needs to perform some actions **after** all the .NET controls have registered themselves. 

Since there is no way to set the execution sequence of $(document).ready(), my question is what is the best pattern to do this sort of thing? I would like the controls to not know anything about the controller.

One of the ways could be to pass the collection of controls to the controller during server render, and then have the controller check periodically if everything is loaded. 

Another way is to 
pass the total number of controls to the controller during render, set a variable (_controlRegisteredCount) on client side which each control will increment during its register stage, and then have the controller poll when (totalControls == _controlRegisteredCount)

Has anyone done such thing before?

Comment: How about callbacks + [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I didn't understand your problem, but as far as I know, the order of execution of the different handlers you add to jQuery's .ready() event is the same as the order you used first to register them.

Take a look at here: [Order of execution of jquery document ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934570/order-of-execution-of-jquery-document-ready)

Comment: Interesting. My superiors mentioned that the handlers DO NOT execute in the same order. I will run a test and then mark your answer. Thanks