# What is JQuery Ready List?

Tags: jquery

I was asked this question in an interview. I searched the web and found the following link and went through this [link](https://gist.github.com/ralphholzmann/663043)

```
(function(){

  jQuery = $ = function( fn ) {
    return typeof fn === "function" ?
      jQuery.readyList.push( fn ) :
      { ready : arguments.callee };
  };

  jQuery.readyList = [];

}).call(window);
```

Does it give me more power to do stuff before dom has been loaded or it is just a piece of knowledge I should keep with me and leave rest to JQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3934584/3354492 This will answer your question

Answer (score 4):

`readyList` used to feature heavily in jQuery prior to version 1.5, but has since been made private. Its only use now lies in [jQuery's ready.js file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/76df9e4e389d80bff410a9e5f08b848de1d21a2f/src/core/ready.js) which determines whether the DOM is ready.

In jQuery 1.4 and lower, `readyList` was a public-facing array containing functions to be executed on DOM ready.

`readyList` since jQuery 1.5 is a private [Deferred Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Being asked what this is in an interview seems a bit strange to me, and possibly implies that the code the company is using hasn't been updated from jQuery 1.4.* or lower. jQuery 1.5 was released in January 2011, over 4 years ago.