# Inline JavaScript tags are NOT executed in the written order

Tags: javascript, jquery, execute

When fetching the page with `GET`, I am seeing `bar()` executed before `foo()`. Why? How can I make them be executed in written order?

For jquery Ajax update: scripts are executed in written order, i.e. `foo()` before `bar()`.

```
<div>
   <div>
      <script>$(function(){ foo(); }); </script>
   </div>
   <script>$(function(){ bar(); }); </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You're mentioning AJAX but I don't see any code using AJAX. Your code, as it's written, will execute in order.

Comment: if it's ajax, then there's no guarantee WHAT order responses come in. that's the A in ajax - asynchronous. Assuming both requests do identical things to identical servers, then it's up to the network gods to determine which response gets back first.

Answer (score 0):

`<script>
$(function(){ foo(); });
$(function(){ bar(); });
</script>`

Comment: There's no difference. Each `<script>` tag is executed in order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery ajax and you need them to execute in order, you will have to nest them. Basically you need to execute one of them in a callback of the other function. It would look something like this: (mind you this is somewhat pseudo code because I don't know what your ajax functions look like)

```
<script>
function bar(){
  //does something
};

function foo(){
  $.ajax({
    //options here
    ,complete: function(){
      bar();
    }
  })
};

foo();
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Answer (score -3):

Wrapping your js in $(...) means it will run on document ready, and although there are optimizations it makes, js is run sequentially 99.99% of the time (unless the compiler is smarter than us, which in that .01% it is).

One thing that might help you in this case is...

```
<div>
    <div>
    ...
    </div>
...
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    foo();
    bar();
};
</script>
```

Comment: Even that may not help in case foo() and bar() do asynchronous calls. That's the point of asynchronous calls :)

Comment: This does not appear to be true. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3934584/111266)

Comment: JS *is* run sequentially. If you couldn't count on that, there'd be almost no reason to program in it! Asynchronous operations may run in any order though as it all depends on when they complete.