# in a .js file document.ready() is not firing first

Tags: jquery, document-ready

Recently I upgraded jquery library to 3.5.1 after that document.ready() is not firing first
In the ver 1.x it used to fire first.

Comment: Please visit [ask] and provide [mre].

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934570/order-of-execution-of-jquery-document-ready